# send a value of javascript variable to a angular js variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am reading a csv file and i convert it into an array as a angularjs script but i have to pass it to an variable in angular js
here is a javascript :

```
    $.get("test.csv", function(data) {

        var rows = data.split("\r\n");

                if(rows.length>0){
                    var firstRowCells = GetCSVCells(rows[0], ",");

                    var dataArray = new Array();
                    for(var i=1;i<rows.length;i++)
                    {
                        var cells = GetCSVCells(rows[i], ",");
                        var obj = {};
                        for(var j=0;j<cells.length;j++)
                        {
                            obj[firstRowCells[j]] = cells[j];
                        }
                        dataArray.push(obj);
                    }


                    $("#dvCSV").html('');
                    alert("dataarray"+dataArray);
                    $("#dvCSV").append(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
                    var myjson=JSON.stringify(dataArray);
                    //alert(myjson);
                }
hera atlast value of dataArray variable have to pass to angular js variable
```

and i have to store it in angular js varaiable $scope.test
app.js:

```
angular.module('sortApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.test=$scope.dataf;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use `jQuery.get()` anyway? Use angular's `$http`:

```
angular.module('sortApp', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("test.csv")
    .then(function(data) {
        var rows = data.split("\r\n");
        if(rows.length > 0){
            var firstRowCells = GetCSVCells(rows[0], ",");

            var dataArray = new Array();
            for (var i=1; i < rows.length; i++)
            {
                var cells = GetCSVCells(rows[i], ",");
                var obj = {};
                for(var j=0; j < cells.length; j++)
                {
                    obj[firstRowCells[j]] = cells[j];
                }
                dataArray.push(obj);
            }
            /*
                You shouldn't use jQuery here anyway,
                just bind a scope value to your html...
                $("#dvCSV").html('');
                alert("dataarray"+dataArray);
                $("#dvCSV").append(JSON.stringify(dataArray));
                var myjson=JSON.stringify(dataArray);
            */
            $scope.test = dataArray;
        }
    })
})
```

and in your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="sortApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    {{test}}
</div>
```

Comment: "it is not working" doesn't help me in helping you. Is there an error you're getting? What did you try? Like, it's impossible for me to help you with so little information about your problem...

Comment: i save it as newapp.js:

Answer (score 0):

if you cant use $http than you can achive this using $apply() , look at snippet for basic usage of apply.

```js
function jsfun()
{
  var data = "i am Ouside scope var ";
  var elem = document.getElementById("mainDiv");
  var scope = angular.element(elem).scope();
  
  
  scope.$apply(function(){
  
    scope.data = data;
  })
}

var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

app.controller('demoCtrl',function($scope){

  $scope.data = "";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myapp'>
  <div id="mainDiv" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  
    value from js :: {{data}}
    
    <br>
    <button onclick="jsfun()">get data from js</button>
  </div>  
</div>
```